# UITableView Programado con UITableViewCell en Storyboard

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewcell

Normalmente hago las interfaces tabla-celda en swift mediante programación. Genero mi ViewController que tiene una instancia de UITableView, a su vez genero otra clase que hereda del UITableViewCell y la inicializo en el tableView: cellForRowAt.

Lo que quiero hacer es seguir manteniendo la instancia del tableView de manera programática, pero crear un prototipo de celda en el storyboard para poderla invocar. Creo que he conseguido la mayor parte, pero no logro hacer que funcione:

1. Creo un nuevo View y en el storyboard pongo como elemento base un elemento Table View Cell. Sobre el coloco los elementos que conforman mi celda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Me aseguro de que la celda tenga un identificador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. En el controlador principal agrego mis instancias del table view controller.

   var reviewsTableView: UITableView?
4. En el ViewdidLoad agrego el código para instanciar mi tabla, el nombre de mi identificador **reviewCell**

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   view.backgroundColor = .gray
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   reviewsTableView = UITableView(frame: view.frame)
   reviewsTableView?.delegate = self
   reviewsTableView?.dataSource = self
   reviewsTableView?.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
   reviewsTableView?.register(ReviewCellTVC.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reviewCell")
   view.addSubview(reviewsTableView!)}
   ```
5. En la función cellForRowat de la tabla creo una instancia de mi celda para retonarla

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reviewCell", for: indexPath) as? ReviewCellTVC)!
      cell.nameLB?.text = "Chava Nava"
      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "tableGray")
      cell.selectionStyle = .blue                
      return cell
   }
   ```

He intentado hacer de diferentes formas el unpacking de mi celda (**cell**) pero siempre regresa nil. Además e intentado no registrar la clase quitan la línea

```
reviewsTableView?.register(ReviewCellTVC.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reviewCell")
```

Pero al hacer eso, me dice que no puede parsear del UITableView a ReviewCellTVC

Se que esta es una práctica muy común, pero todos los ejemplos que encuentro hablan de como hacer tanto el tableView como el tableViewCell en el storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema está en que en lugar de registrar la clase de la celda, debes registrar el `nib` ya que estás usando `.xib`s. Lo puedes hacer así:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "ReviewCellTVC", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reviewCell")
```

Quitar la línea de registrar la celda te da un error porque registrar la celda es algo necesario ya que no estás usando storyboards.

No obstante, cual es el motivo por el que creas el `UITableView` programaticamente y la celda en un `.xib`?. Las dos cosas se pueden hacer en un storyboard con una tableView de prototipos y muy fácilmente.

Comment: Funcionó!!! En realidad era mas una cuestión de aprendizaje. Voy a leer más acerca del nib porque no tengo idea a que se refiera, tienes alguna buena referencia en donde pueda aprender mas a que se refiere el nib?

Comment: `UINib` es una clase que representa a un fichero `.xib` en memoria. El nombre es porque los xibs tienen la extensión `.nib` cuando están compilados, si no me equivoco. Puedes ver más info en la documentación original: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinib